# Is it possible to write Rails tests for methods with callback methods?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I want to write a test for the following method:

```
class SomeObject
  def test_method
    do_something = true
    OtherObject.callback_method(do_something) do
      # test method logic
    end
  end
end
```

with callback_method being:

```
class OtherObject
  def self.callback_method(true_or_false)
    #do some global checks
    yield
  end
end
```

Using Minitest is it possible to somehow stub the callback?

I was hoping to do something like:

```
some_object = SomeObject.new()
some_object.stub(:callback_method, true) do
  #assert method logic
end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you mean `OtherObject.stub(:callback_method, true) {}`? This will cause the call to `OtherObject.callback_method` to return `true` when called from inside the block (`{}`) but I am unclear on what exactly you are testing here. [MiniTest::Object#stub Documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/4.2.0/Object:stub)

Comment: @engineersmnky, the 'true' is simply pseudo code, I have no idea how to stub out the callback_method so I can test the test_method logic.  I'm not even sure if stubbing is possible here...

Comment: My point is that it is possible but what do you want `OtherObject.callback_method` to return? What are you actually testing because right now `test_method` returns the value of `OtherObject.callback_method` so stubbing this and making an assertion would be testing that stubbing works

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, the return value isn't really relevant to the test, so returning nil would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can stub methods temporarily in a fashion nearly identical to what you were hoping for. ([Docs for `MiniTest::Object#stub`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/4.2.0/Object:stub))

Since the method you actually want to stub is `OtherObject.callback_method` you would stub it like so

```
OtherObject.stub(:callback_method,return_value) {}
```

Now when `OtherObject.callback_method` is called inside the block (`{}`) it will return the `return_value` rather than actually calling the method. So given your example above the following test will pass:

```
def test_returns_true_when_I_make_it 
  test_obj = SomeObject.new
  OtherObject.stub(:callback_method,true) do 
    assert test_obj.test_method, true
  end
end
```

This is because your `SomeObject#test_method` returns the value of `OtherObject.callback_method` so since I have stubbed that call I am really just testing that the stub worked you could subsitute the `true` values with any equal objects you would like and the test will still pass e.g.

```
def test_returns_foobar_when_I_make_it 
  test_obj = SomeObject.new
  OtherObject.stub(:callback_method,"foobar") do 
    assert test_obj.test_method, "foobar"
  end
end
```